# disabling buttons or other controls during processing

Tags: excel, vba

I have some button controls which fire off lengthy processing.  Do I have to worry about the user pressing the button and firing off another execution while a first execution is active?

I found I could use the click events to disable the button, call the processing routine, and then enable the button.  But this seems fraught with danger if the processing routine fails.

I could add on error stuff in the click routine to catch failures but would any on error calls in the processing routine cancel those out?

Comment: You can set a global flag (or a Static variable in the sub itself if there's just the one processing routine) when you start processing, then clear it again when you're done.  If the routine gets called again, just exit if the flag is set. You do need to make sure you handle any errors such that you can ensure you clear the flag at the end though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to worry about the user pressing the button and firing off
>   another execution while a first execution is active?

No - as long as there's no chance there's any code in your processing which calls `DoEvents`.

Try assigning the following code to a button in your worksheet (you may need to adjust the iterators higher to get sufficient runtime) and clicking an additional button - or doing anything else in Excel for that matter.

```
Sub test()
    For i = 1 To 100
        For j = 1 To 100
            Range("A1").Select
        Next j

    Next i
End Sub
```

An added bonus is it helps illustrate how `.select` causes slower operations in working with Excel...

> I found I could use the click events to disable the button, call the
>   processing routine, and then enable the button. But this seems fraught
>   with danger if the processing routine fails.

It is probably a good idea to include some sort of error handling regardless of simply reenabling buttons for any meaningful operations unless you are the sole user.

> I could add on error stuff in the click routine to catch failures but
>   would any on error calls in the processing routine cancel those out?

You would have to properly account for errors and the different places. The answer to this is "it depends on your implementation."

Comment: I would qualify that as "No - as long as there's no chance there's any code in your processing which calls `DoEvents`"...

Comment: My experience shows that bad things do happen!  The processing routine includes DoEvents calls if that matters.

Comment: If sub a has a on error in effect and it calls sub b which also uses on  error goto 0, does the sub a on error remain in effect and will it go off if sub b fails?

Comment: See the last post here - http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/scope-error-resume-next-t1000511.html

Answer (score 2):

From experience I've found it's safer to expect that you *might* see multiple parallel executions, and plan to avoid them.  Try this with and without the marked line and clicking the button repeatedly:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Static InProgress As Boolean

    If InProgress Then Exit Sub  'try commenting out...

    InProgress = True

    Debug.Print "starting...."
    DoProcessing
    Debug.Print "....Done"

    InProgress = False

End Sub


Sub DoProcessing()
    Dim x As Long, v

    For x = 1 To 1000
        ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 2)
        DoEvents
    Next x

End Sub
```

This specific behavior is caused by the `DoEvents` call - without this you should not see parallel runs, as enderland noted.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to disable the button in its click handler, then re-enable it after calling the processing routine.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim s As Integer
    s = CommandButton2.Enabled
    If s Then
        On Error GoTo Fail
        CommandButton2.Enabled = False
        GetData
Fail:
        CommandButton2.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I also find this more pleasing than removing the default embedded formula =EMBED("Forms.CommandButton.1","") and attaching a macro.

Comment: + 1 I also use a slight variation of this. I simply disable the button in the start and enable it in the end. There is no need to check whether it is enabled or not if the error handling is done properly.

Answer (score 0):

I get the opposite result as enderland, with a button on a form or on a sheet (button from the Forms menu).  I set a static variable that will increment each time the button is pressed, and if I press it while the code is running, it runs and increments again.  So I'd say yes, you need to set a global variable to handle this:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Static Incrementer As Long
Dim i As Long

Incrementer = Incrementer + 1
For i = 1 To 1000
Debug.Print Incrementer
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that it simply does not finish operation so fast that you are clicking it again and adding to the `Incrementer` variable (which is retained beyond the sub scope)?

Comment: @enderland, I don't think so.  I can see the numbers go by in the debug window and the button has that pushed look when I push it again.  I'd be interested to know what results you get it you try it.  I used a static variable so I'd be able to clearly see which iteration it's in when I click it again.

Comment: Try clicking it slowly - like once every 5 seconds and move the loop down to like 5 instead of 1000 - and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @enderland, I did that.  The loop runs and Incrementer increments. Click it again it runs again and Incrementer increments again.  I'm not sure what you expect me to learn from that; it's what I'd expect with a static variable.  My point is that the same thing happens with my version above when the button is clicked while still in the loop.  Mike D asked "Do I have to worry about the user pressing the button and firing off another execution while a first execution is active?"  My code attempted to answer that.  What results do you get when you run it?

Comment: When I make it take longer (say 1 to 10000) and click it multiple times I only see a debug output of 1, regardless of how many times I click it - Excel does not let me actually click until it is done processing. The only time it increments is if I click it after it is done processing (which is because it is a static variable).

Comment: I've tried it now with: an ActiveX button on a sheet, a "Forms" button on a sheet and a button on a Form.  With the ActiveX it only runs once no matter how many times I click.  With the Forms button on a sheet or a button on a form it runs as many times as I click.  I upped the loop to 10,000 and in all cases I'm calling the same code and doing all the clicks during the first iteration.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15474/discussion-between-enderland-and-doug-glancy)